# Removing formatted images from a word document using Python

Tags: python, image, formatting, cpu-word

I have a word document from a colleague who gave me a .docx Microsoft Word file with 90 images on it that need to be extracted so they can be turned into flashcards. I tried using the Python module "docx2txt" which worked ok, but only extracted 34 images. Upon further inspection, I found that it was because when my coworker made the original file, he took screenshots of PowerPoint slides that he had made with about 4-6 of the images on one slide. Then, he would put them in Word and use the built in Word trimming tool to copy the picture several times and trim down to each individual picture he needed in a particular line of the document. Docx2txt copied the pictures files to my designated directly perfectly, but did not keep the formatting. Any picture file he had inserted and "trimmed down" to size, was copied as the full image. Does anyone know of a way to keep the formatting so I don't have to go through and manually copy 90 pictures one by one? Perhaps converting to a .pdf file and using a pdf related module or something? Or might be there some way of using another Python library which will keep the picture formatting? Thanks for any help you can provide! I'm somewhat of a beginner with Python, but love it when I can get it to automate stuff... even if it ends up taking longer to figure out how to do it than just boring myself to death saving the photos manually, lol.

Comment: Hmm... haven't heard of such a function; I'll do a google search.

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/reduce-the-file-size-of-a-picture-in-microsoft-office-8db7211c-d958-457c-babd-194109eb9535

Important: Cropped parts of the picture are not removed from the file, and can potentially be seen by others; including search engines if the cropped image is posted online. **Only the Office desktop apps have the ability** to remove cropped areas from the underlying image file.

Follow the relevant section for Desktop Office (Windows or Mac) note from above it CANNOT work on Web 365.

go to "Other kinds of cropping"

Important: If you delete cropped areas and later change your mind, you can click the Undo  Button Image button to restore them. Deletions can **[ONLY] be undone until the file is saved.**

- **So make a backup copy of the file**

**Select the** picture or **pictures** (If you want **all** selected that should be easy with **CTRL + A** to highlight everything)

Then follow the instructions

- Picture Tools > Format, and in the Adjust group, click Compress Pictures
- Be sure that the Delete cropped areas of pictures check box is selected
- DEselect the Apply only to this picture check box.

Double check a few manually to verify all is well then save a copy.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks KJ, will give that a shot when I get back to my work computer.